# How to Convert o365 Group to Security Group?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

In my Office365 online setup I have an Office365 Group (unified group) and I want to change it to a Mail-Enabled-Security-Group.

I've searched the world over but cannot find a way to do this via powershell.  Is there a command for this?

If you are interested in my reason for doing this, [look at my other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/817144/external-o365-mail-users-receive-plaintext).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to do this.  It *is* possible to [convert a distribution group to an o365](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Convert-an-Exchange-d5e02126) group however.  I have not found documentation to support my statement, but I was told this by a microsoft tech.